# Any way to identify component causing issues from error in React production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am getting an error in production that is not reproducible but want to figure out what component is causing the issue (and ideally, where within that component).

However, the React production build error stack trace only exists within `react.production.min.js` and `react-dom.production.min.js` once I map it to the source map.

Is there anyway to get the component causing the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React =16. You can use Error boundaries -  React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI.

https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Note that error boundaries only catch errors in the components below them in the tree. So you have to wrap this in the App component.

We have some third party libs - https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary